# How can I collect result from nested .forEach in a Java IntStream

Tags: java, arrays, loops, java-stream

I am playing around and trying to solve this problem "Two Sum" with a Java Stream, not using the imperative method:

```
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 18,
Because nums[1] + nums[2] = 7 + 11 = 18,
return [1, 2].
```

And here is my partially working code.  Can anyone help solve?  I just can't figure out how to collect it back up to be returned as a primitive int array :

```
class Solution { 
    public int[] twoSum(int[] input, int target) {
        IntStream.range(0,  input.length)
           .forEach(i -> {
               IntStream.range(0,  input.length)
                   .filter(j -> i != j && input[i] + input[j] == target)
                   .peek(t -> System.out.println(input[t]))
                   .findFirst();
               }
            );
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the output of the above (coming from peek):

```
11
7
```

Comment: you loop and stream approaches are different. The solutions require to keep some global variables, but streams usually transform data with stateless methods. Probably streams are not a perfect approach for this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in comments Streams are not always a perfect solution. But regarding your task, it looks like you need a stream of Pair. Unfortunately Java does not have Tuples (like Scala) that's why I suggest to create a simple `Pair` class.

```
class Pair {
    int i, j;
    public Pair(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }
}
```

Then, work with a stream of pairs

```
 IntStream.range(0,  input.length)
                .boxed()
                .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0,  input.length).boxed()
                                .map(j -> new Pair(i,j))
                )
                        .filter(p -> p.i != p.j)
                        .filter(p -> input[p.i] + input[p.j] == target)
                        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to get it to work with `import javafx.util.Pair;`  .  Resulting list had "duplicate inverse-pairs" in it.  Just had to filter the dupes out.

Answer (score 2):

The common recipe to mimic nested `for` loops that drive a list or an array via indexes is to use `IntStream` along with `flatMap`:

```
int[] input = {12, 7, 11, 15, 6, 2};
int target = 18;

List<List<Integer>> result = IntStream.range(0, input.length)
    .boxed()
    .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i + 1, input.length)
        .filter(j -> input[i] + input[j] == target)
        .mapToObj(j -> Arrays.asList(i, j)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result); // [[0, 4], [1, 2]]
```

Note that you don't need a `Pair` class to maintain state from the inner stream to the outer stream, because you can apply the needed filter to the inner stream.

Besides, the inner `IntStream` is not required to start on `0`, because you don't want to have both `[i, j]` and `[j, i]` in the result (only one of them is needed). So starting the inner `IntStream` with `i + 1` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be resolved with time complexity O(n):

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> indexMap = IntStream.range(0, a.length).boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> a[i]));

IntStream.range(0, a.length)
    .boxed()
    .filter(i -> indexMap.containsKey(target - a[i]))
    .flatMap(i -> indexMap.get(target - a[i]).stream().filter(j -> i < j).map(j -> Pair.of(i, j)))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```